# HP Fortify SSC 4.3 Code Line Number Mismatch

Tags: security, fortify

All,
I am reviewing some Fortify has detected and some of the 'issues' are showing line numbers higher than the total line count of the code.  E.G. Error on line 599 & there are only 490 lines of code in the file.

I have verified the versions and ensured that the correct path is used.

Does anyone know why this is occurring.  There are more than 50 'errors' that are showing this type of situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there libraries or other dependencies invoked by the subject code?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the source code has changed since you last scanned it.  The FPR contains the original source code that was scanned, but when opening the FPR, if Fortify detects the source code in the original path (the path that was scanned) it will use that instead (I think it is a performance thing).

When Fortify goes to display source code and cannot find code at the external path of the scan, it will then display a message:

```
The current source path is invalid, but the project contains a copy of the 
scanned source code. Would you like to extract the source code to a location      
on disk, or update the path to an existing location?
```

With three options:

- Use Source Included in FPR
- Cancel
- Update Path

If you want exactly what was scan then choose the first option

If you want it to point Fortify to the location of the source code on your system use the third option.

If you want it to use the internal source then do the following

Open the FPR
Do Tool -> Extract Source Code
Pick a location
When you do this, Fortify will automatically start using that location to pull the source code for display.